# adding tag on mailchimp via api replies success but no tags are added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Here's my method to add tags to an existing Mailchimp subscriber:

```
def self.add_tag_on_mailchimp(email,tag)
    begin
      mailchimp = MailchimpMarketing::Client.new
      mailchimp.set_config({
                             :api_key => Rails.configuration.mailchimp_api_key,
                             :server => "us2"
      })
      lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email.downcase)
      response = mailchimp.lists.update_list_member_tags(
        '6181dc4fdc', lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address,{
          body: {
            tags: [
              {
                name: tag,
                status: "active"
              }
            ]
          }
      })
      p "reply from mailchimp: #{response}"
      p  "added #{tag} tag"
    rescue MailchimpMarketing::ApiError => e
      puts "Error: #{e}. trying to create"
    end
  end
```

The call returns "success" if the email exists, but the tags aren't added at all. I tried sending tags that existed or not on Mailchimp, and I always get success, but there are no tags on Mailchimp.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY8v3MQoU3g to connect your ruby on rails app users to your mailchimp account list

Answer (score 0):

the mailchimp-marketing gem is buggy. I switched to the gibbons gem and it's all good.